# What is Object details in Chrome.* API

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, method-signature

I am learning Chrome extension development  from the official documentation and learned a bit but I need understanding what it means by **object details** in API function parameters. For example one of [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-getTitle) method **getTitle** signature  is

```
chrome.browserAction.getTitle(object details, function callback)

//object details     integer    (optional) tabId
```

Now I write in **background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.getTitle({}, titleShow);
function titleShow(t){
 console.log('tab title:' + t);
}
```

and it show title of my extension.As you can see here I send blank object `{}`.

How do I get **tabId** on very first line and send it with this method?

Does this method return tab Title if we send tab id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking questions that are easy to answer, just check [**the documentation**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction%23method-getTitle) and you'll see the details of the `chrome.browserAction.getTitle()` method (and all the other methods of the Chrome APIs).

Quoting from the documentation:

> `chrome.browserAction.getTitle(object details, function callback)`
>
> Gets the title of the browser action.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - object `details`:
>
>   - integer (optional) `tabId`. Specify the tab to get the title from. If no tab is specified, the non-tab-specific title is returned.
> - function `callBack`. The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this: `function(string result) {...};`
>
>   - string `result`.

**So, to answer your questions:**

1. To get the tab id on the first line you've got to use the `chrome.tabs.query()` method ([**see documentation**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs%23method-query)), request the tab with the details you're interested in and use its ID in the callback, something like this:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
       chrome.browserAction.getTitle({tabId: tabs[0].id}, function(result) { 
           console.log("Browser action title:", result);
       });
   });
   ```
2. Browser actions can have different titles on different tabs. To set a different title for each tab you have to use the `chrome.browserAction.setTitle()` method. So if you send the `tabId` in the details object of the `chrome.browserAction.getTitle()` method, **you'll not get the tab title, you'll only get the tab-specific title of the browser action**. To get a specific tab title you should use the `chrome.tabs.query()` method.

Comment: Thank you Marco. I have read the documentation but then get confused so I asked.I know it's a very easy to answer for you all genius guys here :)  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I have followed your instructions, it always gives me extension Title only.  
**my guess:** background page can only be visible through `chrome://extensions/` page  so moved  code from **background.js** to **popup.js** but still gives only the extension title name not that active tab title, even it gives different tab ID

Comment: @diEcho read my question, I didn't say that the function returns the tab title (in fact it doesn't). And the fact that it returns your extension title it's because your browser action actually **has** that title. To change the title of the browser action tou should either use the "default_title" field in the manifest or the chrome.browserAction.setTitle method in the background page.

Comment: Yes, I have written `default_title` in **manifest.json** and that what it returns. So Now my question is How to get active Tab title instead of extension title and what is the usage of `tabId` parameter in this method when we are receiving the same extension title with or without the `tabId`. Would you please explain this.

Comment: @diEcho I already explained it! Since that you can set different titles for the browser action in different tabs using the chrome.browserAction.setTitle method, then if you use the tabId in the getTitle method you'll get the specific title of the browser action in that tab. If you don't set any different title obviously you'll always get the same title. For the other question (how to get the tab titile) you should ask a different question, because it hasn't much to do with this one.

Comment: somehow it stops working. doesn't show any console thing while inspect this extension. it's strange and annoying. Is this because I shifted code to `popup.js` ?

Comment: @diEcho you can use that code in popup.js, I don't cannot know what's the error in your code...

Comment: @diEcho obviously if you use the code in popup.js you have to look at the popup console, not the tab or background console

Comment: see my code here:  all 3 files popup.html , popup.js and manifest.json
http://pastebin.com/u/xkeshav

Comment: @diEcho you cannot use the "tabId" variable, which doesn't exist, in your console.log. Use tabs[0].id instead

Comment: @diEcho add more logs (like one log for the tabs array) and see what happens. I cannot debug that for you

Comment: Oh, get it.Thanks. Why chrome didn't give any error :\